# what formula / keyword should I use to solve in excel?

Tags: excel

If I have data like this in excel

```
Name   || Fruit        ||  things || element   
David  || Apple        ||  pencil || wind
Ana    || Banana       ||  eraser || water
Calum  || watermelon   ||  pen    || earth
Noah   || kiwi         ||  ruler  || fire
```

And, I want to find out who has the same object with the three objects above in a data table. I want to find out who is name.

```
Fruit     ||   things   || element    
Banana    ||   eraser   || water
```

To be sure, the name that came out was "Ana".
But i don't know what formula in excel for this.

And, What if there are 2 or more people who have the same data, can all the requested names appear in one search result?

What formula should I use to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use what's called index match. You can concatenate the inputs with the `&`

https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: Oh,it works! Thanks...
 but it doesn't work to display two names if the data is the same.

Comment: You're getting into a world where VBA is a MUCH better option - you could probably get a function to work but it will be painfully slow on large datasets

Comment: Okay, at least I will learn the basics first. Thank you for your help and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some VBA to do this for you:

```
Function multiLookup(lookup_value, value_array As range, lookup_array, Optional delim = ",", Optional error_val = "Error")
    multiLookup = "<Not Found>"
    On Error GoTo error
        lookup_ct = UBound(lookup_array, 1) - LBound(lookup_array, 1) + 1

        If lookup_ct <> value_array.Count Then GoTo error

        For i = 1 To value_array.Count
            Debug.Print value_array(i), lookup_array(i, 1)
            If lookup_array(i, 1) = lookup_value Then
                If multiLookup <> "" Then
                    If multiLookup = "<Not Found>" Then
                        multiLookup = ""
                    Else
                        multiLookup = multiLookup & delim & " "
                    End If
                End If
                multiLookup = multiLookup & value_array(i)
            End If
        Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
error:
    multiLookup = error_val
End Function
```

with the following table (Cells A1:D6 for example use):

```
Name|Fruit|things|element
David|Apple|pencil|wind
Ana|Banana|eraser|water
Calum|watermelon|pen|earth
Noah|kiwi|ruler|fire
Tom|Banana|eraser|water
```

I then created an input (Cells B8:D8 for example):

```
Banana|eraser|water
```

In Cell A8 I added the following *index function:

```
=multiLookup(B8&C8&D8,A1:A6,B1:B6&C1:C6&D1:D6)
```

*index functions must be entered with a Shift+Enter

this returns `Ana, Tom`

**Documentation**

```
lookup_value: this is the target value (in this case Bananaeraserwater from B8:D8)
value_array: this is the label array (in this case the name column)
lookup_array: this is the concatenated data array (fruit col & things col & element col)
delim: Default is a comma, this is the mark that separates output values
error_val: Default is "Error" this is the function return value if there is an error (most likely value_array is not the same length as lookup_array)
```

Comment: @tav can you mark one of these answers as correct please?